# my program is to post to mysql database. I am having issues, and I have tried for hours to determine where I am wrong

Tags: php, mysql

Like the title says, when I was just going from the registration page to the confirmation page I was okay.  Adding in the ability to post to the database I am having difficulties.

Registration Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project_style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h2>Registration</h2>
</header>

<?php include "menu.php"; ?> 

  <h3>Registration</h3>

  <p><form method="post" action="Registration_results.php">



KSU Net ID: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="ksuid"

   placeholder="Enter your KSU ID"

   title="You must type at least three letters."

   pattern="\w{3,}" required>
</p>
  <p>

First Name: &emsp;<input type="text" name="fname" 

   placeholder="Enter your first name"

   title="You must type at least three letters."

   pattern="\w{3,}" required></p>
  <p>

Last Name:&emsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="lname"

   placeholder="Enter your last name"

   title="You must type at least three letters."

   pattern="\w{3,}" required></p>
  <p>

Email: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="email"

   placeholder="Enter your Email address"
</p>


  <p>Services Offered:

  <select id="service" name="service">

       <option value="">Select Service</option>

          <option value="">Math Tutoring<Math</option>

          <option value="">Programming Tutoring<Programming</option>

          <option value="">English Tutoring<English</option>

          <option value="">Nuclear Fission Tester<Nuclear Fission Tester</option>

        </select>
        </p>

        <p> Availability:
  <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Monday"> Monday<br>
  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;        <input type="checkbox" name="date[]"     value="Tuesday"> Tuesday<br>
  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;     <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Wednesday"> Wednesday<br>
  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;    <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Thursday"> Thursday<br>
  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;    <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Friday"> Friday<br>
  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;   <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Saturday"> Saturday<br>
  &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;   <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Sunday"> Sunday<br>

        </p>


  <input type="checkbox" name="notification" value="Email"> I would like to receive email notification<br>
</p>
<p><input type=submit value="Submit"></p>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Results page that should prompt posting to database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>Results</title>

</head>
<?php include "menu.php"; ?> 


<body>


  <?php 
    $all_information_provided = 1;


  if (!empty($_POST['ksuid'])) {

    $ksuid = $_POST['ksuid'];

    echo "<p>KSU ID: $ksuid </p>";

  } else {

    echo "<p>No ID was entered.</p>";
}

if (!empty($_POST['fname'])) {

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];

    echo "<p>First Name: $fname </p>";

  } else {

    echo "<p>No First Name was entered.</p>";
$all_information_provided = 0;
}

if (!empty($_POST['lname'])) {

    $lname = $_POST['lname'];

    echo "<p>Last Name: $lname </p>";

  } else {

    echo "<p>No Last Name was entered.</p>";
$all_information_provided = 0;
}

if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    echo "<p>The entered email is: $email </p>";

  } else {

    echo "<p>No email was entered.</p>";
$all_information_provided = 0;
}


  if (!empty($_POST['service'])) {

    $selected_entry = $_POST['service'];

    echo "<p>Service: $selected_entry </p>";

  } else {

    echo "<p>No service was selected.</p>";
$all_information_provided = 0;


}

  if(!empty($_POST['date'])){


    $date = implode(",", $_POST['date']);

    echo "<p>Day: $date </p>";


  } else {

    echo "<p>No days were provided.</p>";
$all_information_provided = 0;

  }

if(!empty($_POST['notification'])){


    $notification = implode(",", $_POST['notification']);

    echo "<p>You will be signed up for future notification: $notification </p>";


  } else {

    echo "<p>You will not receive future notifications notification.</p>";
$all_information_provided = 0;

  }

$to = $email;

  $msg = "Thank you for completing our form.";

  $subject = "Registration";


  $body = $msg;

  if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {

    echo("<p>Confirmation email message successfully sent!</p>");

  } else {

    echo("<p>Confirmation email message delivery failed...</p>");

  }

if($all_information_provided == 1){

     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hank",

       "my*password", "hhill")

        or die("Cannot connect to database:" .

           mysqli_connect_error($conn));

$query = mysqli_prepare($conn,

    "INSERT INTO profile (fname, lname, email, service, date, notification) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")

        or die("Error: ". mysqli_error($conn));

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query, "ss", $selected_radio, $selected_entry);

 mysqli_stmt_execute($query)

       or die("Error. Could not insert into the table."

                   . mysqli_error($conn));

$inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

   echo "Your data was recorded. It is entry #" . $inserted_id;

   mysqli_stmt_close($query); 

foreach($_POST['service'] as $service) {

      $query = mysqli_prepare($conn,

       "INSERT INTO services(ID, service) VALUES(?, ?)")

          or die("Error: ". mysqli_error($conn));

  ?>



</body>

</html>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're binding for this `VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` and the one you're doing is placed below your `ss`. What did error checking throw back?

Comment: Go through the manuals if you haven't already http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\Registration_results.php on line 184

Comment: @HailHydra A lot more lately ;-)

Comment: quite a few errors with your code. You could probably patch it up with a mix of those 2 answers below, where one covers something that the other did not.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query, "ss", $selected_radio, $selected_entry);  you are missing 4 more parameters to bind here. please look at the answer below

Comment: does the manual show to use 6x placeholders and 2 binds? No. Do the math here. 2 is not equal to 6.

Comment: you also don't have multiple arrays of `$_POST['service']`. That is for your `<select>` (and no values for them) and only have a choice of one from many, not many choices of many unlike your checkboxes. You should be getting an error about that also. No idea why you want to do this `implode(",", $_POST['notification'])` for a single input and an `!empty()` for a checkbox; you need `isset()` for that. Your code has more errors that I have seen in a long time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Fred, I am reading through the manual and trying to work out some of this based on your guys feedback.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't closed your foreach block with a }

Comment: you missed one, not just for the `foreach`. and it's only 50% of the problem.

Comment: yeah also for his last if statement he has missed a closing parenthesis

Comment: I added the brackets, and not the program returns the page formatted as expected - but still doesn't post to the database

Answer (score 1):

In first insert query you are not binding all 6 values to query

```
query = mysqli_prepare($conn,

"INSERT INTO profile (fname, lname, email, service, date, notification) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")

    or die("Error: ". mysqli_error($conn));

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query, "ss", $selected_radio, $selected_entry);
```

Another error, here you are not binding parameters

```
   $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO services(ID, service) VALUES(?, ?)")
```

Comment: should it look more like: 

        or die("Error: ". mysqli_error($conn));

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($query, "ss", $fname, $lname, $email, $service, $date, $notification);

Comment: Sorry posted wrong answer - didnt read script properly :-( removed the answer